# Urgent: Bird hatchling identification

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Yesterday evening I found this baby bird in one corner of my house's verandah on the floor. I picked it up and placed it safely in a tray hoping that tomorrow morning its parents will find it (actually I initially suspected it to be a sparrow hatchling). When I saw it today morning I found that it is probably a bird of prey. As you can notice the large long beak and claws.
I'm really confused now what to do with it. Please suggest something.[image: enter image description]
[image: enter image descript]
[image: pic]

EDIT

- I live in Uttar Pradesh, India.
- Its relatively plain where I live. (No mountains or lake nearby)
- Temperature: 35-20 degrees Celsius
- Added a photo for size estimation

[image: pic2]

Comment: RSPCA would be a good start.

Comment: Identification may or may not be possible, but more information is needed, e.g. your location, bird size indication, and whether near seacoast, lake or mountains..

Comment: @GrahamChiu What's that?

Comment: Royal Society for Prevention to Cruelty to Animals.

Comment: https://www.peta.org/action/how-to-save-baby-birds/

Comment: Actually I found a nest of "Laughing Dove" in my yard. I've placed the baby back into the nest.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughing_dove

Comment: Yes, it is a most probably a laughing dove

Comment: @Serotonin I guess, you already know that you can write (and accept) your own question and describe, why/how you identified the hatchling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've pictured this is a fledgling that you found which has a mixture of adult feathers and immature feathers.  This indicates that it flew to your location, and a nest is nearby.  You should either attempt to find the nest, or just leave the fledgling alone and let it make its own way home as indicated in this [online resource](https://www.peta.org/action/how-to-save-baby-birds/).

> Fledglings are juvenile birds who have a mix of fuzzy down and adult feathers and are learning to fly. You may come across them hopping along on the ground, perching on low-hanging branches, or hiding under bushes, but as long as they’re healthy, just let them be.
>
> **Note: Fledglings are often “rescued” from their natural environment when they don’t need to be**.